# Using libraries such as Leaflet or OpenLayers with Vue.js without breaking DOM?

Tags: vuejs2, leaflet, openlayers

The JS libraries that are meant for showing maps on the web pages and I guess many other libraries that visualize data on the web pages often modify  the DOM quite heavily.

If I want to use such library with Vue.js and there is no fitting library adaption available for Vue.js then what are the best practices for adapting them, so that the DOM is updated properly and I can use the libraries safely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, for Vue or for any library, I just play with the lifecycle of the JavaScript framework.

In Vue, I create my map in `mounted` cycle (see [the diagram](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) from the official doc) because Openlayers like Leaflet both need a DOM element mounted to bind the map related elements.

It's the same if using React, you just use `componentDidMount` (see the [React lifecycle diagram](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/))

Comment: But how about if I would like to create and use Vue components within the map? Also, at least using the OpenLayers [overlay](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Overlay-Overlay.html) seems to cause occasional errors.

Comment: Did you look at components in libraries using Vue + Openlayers https://github.com/ghettovoice/vuelayers/blob/master/src/component/overlay/overlay.vue ? It should help (PS: I assume I don't have a good answer to the second question from your comment, hence my redirection to the code sample)

Comment: @Orienteerix "_how about if I would like to create and use Vue components within the map?_": please be specific and include details in your question (you can _edit_ it), possibly with some sample code. Questions without a clear and specific problem statement usually lead to miscommunication, lack of relevant answer for the questioner, lenghty comments trying to add new requirements, and finally frustration of everyone.

Comment: @ThomasGratier I agree that looking into the existing library implementation helps.

Comment: @ghybs Ok, I try to be more specific in future. I would delete the question if it was possible, I flagged it with close request.